# OCaml, Collatz sequence, can't print the result

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to make a program to compute the length of the Collatz sequence on all numbers from 1 to 100. Basically if I have an odd number I have to multiply it by 3 and add 1(n*3+1), and if I have a even number I need to divide it by 2(n/2) and then keep doing it untill it gets to 1 and in the end print out the count of times the number was either divided by 2 or multiplyed by 3 and added 1.
Here is what i have so far:

```
let stevec = ref 0;
let n = ref 1;
for i = 1 to 100 do
    n := i;
    while !n != 1 do
        if (n mod 2 = 0) then 
            stevec := !stevec + 1;
            n := !n / 2;
        if (n mod 2 = 1) then
            stevec := !stevec + 1;
            n := 3 * !n + 1;
    done
    print_int (stevec);
done;;
```

After I run the code I get a syntax error and the print_int get underlined so i guess there is a problem with that but I'm not even sure about that.

Comment: I can fix the syntax errors, but when I ran the code it doesn't terminate, so i think there are logic issues in the code.

Comment: Have you tried using functionnal programming instead of side effects? Your OCaml code will be both more readable and writable if you do so.

Comment: I'm just learning Ocaml but I'm quiet sure that in a language like java or python this logic should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, so let's take a look at it.

```
let stevec = ref 0;
let n = ref 1;
```

You shouldn't write that kind of code, as `;` is an expression separator (and you are using it here as a declaration separator).

The right approach depends on wether you want your declaration to be local or toplevel.

```
(* local declaration *)
let stevec = ref 0 in
let n = ref 1 in

(* toplevel declaration *)
let stevec = ref 0;;
let n = ref 1;;
```

Then you typed `while !n != 1 do`. This shouldn't be used as you do physical inequality between your integers, whereas you want structural equality. Well, it will work too because of OCaml's behavior on integers but good practice requires you to use `<>` instead of `!=`.

Now let's look at your loop's body:

```
if (!n mod 2 = 0) then 
   stevec := !stevec + 1;
   n := !n / 2;
if (!n mod 2 = 1) then
   stevec := !stevec + 1;
   n := 3 * !n + 1;
```

Notice the absence of any `fi` or closing bracket? That's because in OCaml, only the next expression after the `then` is executed. And precedence over `;` doesn't go as you want it to. You can use parens or the more explicit `begin ... end` construction. To prove that the `begin ... end` works, I replaced your second test by a `else` statement.

```
if (!n mod 2 = 0) then
   begin
    stevec := !stevec + 1;
    n := !n / 2;
   end
else
   begin
    stevec := !stevec + 1;
    n := 3 * !n + 1;
   end
```

Finally `while ... done` being itself an expression, you should put a `;` at the end of it.

And that's how you remove the errors from your code.
Yet...

This is clearly not the "right way" to do it in OCaml. The main perk of FP is its closeness to maths and you are here trying to define a mathematical function. So let's do this in a functionnal way:

```
let is_even x = (x mod 2) = 0;;
let rec collatz counter n =
  if n = 1
  then counter
  else collatz (counter+1) (if is_even n then n/2 else 3*n+1);;
let () =
 for i = 1 to 100 do
  print_int (collatz 0 i);
  print_newline ();
 done;;
```

Doesn't that look nicer? Feel free to ask for any clarification of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain. I do have a question about (let rec collatz counter n =). how does that collatz counter in the middle of (let rec n)  work, what does it do exactly. I'm just not familar with this type of coding.

Comment: Basically, this line declares (that's the `let`) a recursive (`rec`) function named `collatz` that takes two arguments `counter` and `n`. Making it recursive allows `collatz` to call itself hence allowing it to loop (this is how loops are implemented in functionnal programming).

Comment: You should take a look at the ocaml.org's "basics of OCaml" page: http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html

Comment: ok, now i get it. What if I wanted to find the n that had the highest counter, should I try doing it with arrays or is there any better way?

Comment: You can simply do a loop that always remember the best result so far and compares it with your next collatz call. If your code has speed issues, memoization would help (but not on an array as you don't know how far up `n` could go).